# Getting NA on a merge that incorporates a second pair of columns in an either/or type of match

Tags: r, merge

I would like to merge two data frames matching on either/or of two pairs of columns.  The idea is to give me a merge if a either Date1 or Date2 in the first dataframe match Date3 in the second data frame.  First I duplicated the Date3 into Date3A and Date3B, because matching 2 to 1 gave an error. And while it runs here in the sample data, it only appended NA to each row in my real data.

```
IDx<-c("A","B","C","D")
Date1<-c("04-04-2004","05-05-2005","06-06-2006", "07-07-2007")
Date2<-c("04-04-2005","05-05-2005","06-06-2007","05-05-2005")
dfx<-data.frame(IDx,Date1,Date2)
# dfx looks like
#  IDx      Date1      Date2
#1   A 04-04-2004 04-04-2005
#2   B 05-05-2005 05-05-2005
#3   C 06-06-2006 06-06-2007
#4   D 07-07-2007 05-05-2005

IDy<-c("E","F","G","H")
Date3A<-c("04-04-2008","05-05-2005","06-06-2006","07-07-2007")
Date3B<-c("04-04-2008","05-05-2005","06-06-2006","07-07-2007")
dfy<-data.frame(IDy, Date3A,Date3B)
#note that Date3A and Date3B are exact matches.
# dfy
#  IDy     Date3A     Date3B
#1   E 04-04-2008 04-04-2008
#2   F 05-05-2005 05-05-2005
#3   G 06-06-2006 06-06-2006
#4   H 07-07-2007 07-07-2007
```

Here is what I tried

```
NewDF<-merge(x=dfx, y=dfy, by.x =c("Date1", "Date2"), by.y=c("Date3A","Date3B"), all.x=TRUE)

#NewDF looks like 
#       Date1 IDx      Date2  IDy     Date3B
#1 04-04-2004   A 04-04-2005 <NA>       <NA>
#2 05-05-2005   B 05-05-2005    F 05-05-2005
#3 06-06-2006   C 06-06-2007    G 06-06-2006
#4 07-07-2007   D 05-05-2005    H 07-07-2007
```

I should be getting a fifth row to match D with either H or F.
Here it runs, but when I tried it with my real data, it only appended NA to each row.
So, for now, I am running them twice, like so

```
NewDF<-merge(x=dfx, y=dfy, by.x =c("Date1"), by.y=c("Date3A"), all.x=TRUE)
NewDF2<-merge(x=NewDF, y=dfy, by.x =c("Date2"), by.y=c("Date3A"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Now I get the right answer but the matches appear twice in each row (wide) and I want the matches to be one to each row (long).

```
#> NewDF2
#       Date2      Date1 IDx IDy.x   Date3B.x IDy.y   Date3B.y
#1 04-04-2005 04-04-2004   A  <NA>       <NA>  <NA>       <NA>
#2 05-05-2005 05-05-2005   B     F 05-05-2005     F 05-05-2005
#3 05-05-2005 07-07-2007   D     H 07-07-2007     F 05-05-2005
#4 06-06-2007 06-06-2006   C     G 06-06-2006  <NA>       <NA>
```

Can anyone help figure out what is going wrong?  There are no NA's in the Date3 column(s).

Comment: Consider implementing ["non-equi joins"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins) with `data.table` (most efficient) or `sqldf` (syntactically ergonomic for SQL users).  Using `merge` can be a bit of a pain.

Comment: What should happen if two different rows in the second data frame match with date1 and date2?

Comment: Good Question, @MartinWettstein, and I edited my own question to illuminate that aspect of the problem.

Comment: I think you are right, Greg, I should find a data.table solution, I was hoping someone would help me figure it out, but I'll keep working on it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find for *all* rows of `dfx` those `IDy` in `dfy` where `Date3` matches either `Date1` or `Date2`. The result is expected in long format.

Here are 3 different approaches:

1. Reshape and join
2. Two separate joins and a union
3. Recursive joins and reshape (similar to OP's approach)

#### 1. Reshape and join

`dfx` is reshaped from wide to long format so that there is only one date column which is used to join with `dfy`. Finally, this intermediate result is joined again with the `dfx` (to include `IDx == A` which does not have any matching date in `dfy` in the final result):

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dfx), id.var = "IDx", value.name = "Date3")[
  setDT(dfy), on = "Date3", nomatch = NULL][
    , unique(.SD), .SDcols = !"variable"][
      dfx, on = "IDx"]
```

> ```
>    IDx      Date3  IDy      Date1      Date2
> 1:   A       <NA> <NA> 04-04-2004 04-04-2005
> 2:   B 05-05-2005    F 05-05-2005 05-05-2005
> 3:   C 06-06-2006    G 06-06-2006 06-06-2007
> 4:   D 05-05-2005    F 07-07-2007 05-05-2005
> 5:   D 07-07-2007    H 07-07-2007 05-05-2005
> ```

#### 2. Two separate joins and a union

One join is on the first date column `Date1`, the other join is on the second date column `Date2`. Both intermediate results are then combined rowwise (a *union* in SQL) and reordered:

```
library(data.table)
rbind(
  setDT(dfy)[setDT(dfx), on = "Date3==Date1", .(IDx, Date1, Date2, IDy, Date3)], 
  setDT(dfy)[setDT(dfx), on = "Date3==Date2", .(IDx, Date1, Date2, IDy, Date3)]
)[order(IDx)]
```

> ```
>    IDx      Date1      Date2  IDy      Date3
> 1:   A 04-04-2004 04-04-2005 <NA> 04-04-2004
> 2:   A 04-04-2004 04-04-2005 <NA> 04-04-2005
> 3:   B 05-05-2005 05-05-2005    F 05-05-2005
> 4:   B 05-05-2005 05-05-2005    F 05-05-2005
> 5:   C 06-06-2006 06-06-2007    G 06-06-2006
> 6:   C 06-06-2006 06-06-2007 <NA> 06-06-2007
> 7:   D 07-07-2007 05-05-2005    H 07-07-2007
> 8:   D 07-07-2007 05-05-2005    F 05-05-2005
> ```

#### 3. Recursive joins and reshape

`dfx` is right-joined with `dfy` to find matching dates in `Date2`. The intermediate result is again right-joined with `dfy` to find matching dates in `Date1`. Finally, the result is reshaped from wide to long format.

This is similar to OP's approach where the result of the first `merge()` is merged again.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfy)[dfy[setDT(dfx), on = "Date3==Date2"], on = "Date3==Date1"][
  , melt(.SD, id.vars = "IDx", measure.vars = patterns(IDy ="IDy$", Date = "Date3$"))][
    order(IDx), !"variable"]
```

> ```
>    IDx  IDy       Date
> 1:   A <NA> 04-04-2004
> 2:   A <NA> 04-04-2005
> 3:   B    F 05-05-2005
> 4:   B    F 05-05-2005
> 5:   C    G 06-06-2006
> 6:   C <NA> 06-06-2007
> 7:   D    H 07-07-2007
> 8:   D    F 05-05-2005
> ```

For each row in `dfx` the result has two rows.

- In case `IDx == A` there is no matching date in `dfy` which is indicated by the two `NA`
- In case `IDx == B` there is one matching date in `dfy` but appears duplicated because `Date1` and `Date2` contain the same date value
- In case `IDx == C` there is one matching date in `dfy`. For `Date2` there is no match which is indicated by `NA`
- In case `IDx == D` there are two matching dates in `dfy`

#### Data

```
IDx <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Date1 <- c("04-04-2004", "05-05-2005", "06-06-2006", "07-07-2007")
Date2 <- c("04-04-2005", "05-05-2005", "06-06-2007", "05-05-2005")
dfx <- data.frame(IDx, Date1, Date2)

IDy <- c("E", "F", "G", "H")
Date3 <- c("04-04-2008", "05-05-2005", "06-06-2006", "07-07-2007")
dfy <- data.frame(IDy, Date3)
```

Comment: This is awesome @Uwe.  And yesterday my boss asked me to do the same thing but with a fuzzy match 15 days before and 15 days after , because we didn't get as many matches as we expected.  So I am back to the drawing board!  Any ideas for where to start hunting?

Comment: Thank you, @RLP. The `data.table` package provides some tools for finding matches in date ranges: *non-equi joins*, the `foverlaps()`, and the `inrange()` functions. Also, `SQL` can do this (in R using the `sqldf` package). Please, search the `data.table` tag for answers containing the phrase *non-equi join* or post a new question with appropriate sample datasets - thank you.